# can I still optimize my JS so that it is faster

Tags: javascript, html, optimization

It works!

You wouldn't believe how annoying that was.

Here is the working code, can someone help me to optimize the code?

are there any tricks to shorten the js or just make it faster?
(The site also runs pagespeed, the js is already optimized, but is still a bit slow)

JS:

```js
    window.onload = function checkCookie() {
    if (document.cookie.split(';').some((item) => item.trim().startsWith('TechStatCookie='))) {
        document.getElementById("CookiePopup").style.display = "none";
        console.log("TechStatCookie detected ");
    }
    else {
        console.log("TechStatCookie NOT detected ");
    }
};


function _yesCookie() {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setTime(now.getTime() + 2419200000);
    document.cookie = "YesCookie = set; expires=; path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure" + now.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "TechStatCookie=1; expires=; path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure" + now.toUTCString();

    console.log("TechStatCookie set " + now.toUTCString());

    document.cookie = 'NoCookie=; Max-Age=-99999999; path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure';
    window.ga = window.ga || function() {
        (ga.q = ga.q || []).push(arguments)

    };
    ga.l = +new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    var gascript = document.createElement("script");
    gascript.async = true;
    gascript.src = "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(gascript, document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]);
    console.log("Tracking enabled! " + now.toUTCString());
    document.getElementById("CookiePopup").style.display = "none";
}

function _noCookie() {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setTime(now.getTime() + 604800000);
    document.cookie = "NoCookie = set; expires=; path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure" + now.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "TechStatCookie=1; expires=; path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure" + now.toUTCString();

    console.log("TechStatCookie set " + now.toUTCString());

    document.cookie = 'YesCookie=; Max-Age=-99999999; path=/; SameSite=Strict; Secure';
    console.log("Tracking disabled... " + now.toUTCString());
    document.getElementById("CookiePopup").style.display = "none";
}
```

Html:

```html
    <section id="CookiePopup">
        <br>
        <h1>Datenschutz</h1><br>
        <embed src="https://example.com/update.html" width="100%" height="250px">
        <p>blablabla</p>
        <br>
        <button class="ycookie" onclick='_yesCookie()' title="OK"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i></button>
        <button class="ncookie" onclick='_noCookie()' title="NEIN"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></button>
    </section>
```

Comment: Because your `function` declarations are nested in another scope (the `try` block) they aren't promoted to global-level functions.

Comment: To fix it, just remove the `try` statement (and its braces, and the `catch` block) - or forward-declare the functions outside the `try` and define them within the `try`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't import the JS file in html.

```
<script src="./example.js"></script>
```

Comment: oh sry, i forgot, the import is contained in the html

Comment: So, did you fix it?

Comment: Not really :/

The script runs, but the popup is also displayed after I got the "TechStatCookie"... (So the popup should not be displayed)

Comment: To get cookie variable:     var techStatCookie = new RegExp('(?:^|; )TechStatCookie=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie);

Comment: I have tried it with " var techStatCookie = new RegExp('(?:^|; )TechStatCookie=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie); ", unfortunately it does not work with that and with my code " document.cookie = "TechStatCookie=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; SameSite=Strict; Secure"; "

Comment: The actual code is in my answer, Code to show/hide:   document.onload = function() {
if (!document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('TechStatCookie'))) {

    document.getElementById("CookiePopup").style.display = "none";
    console.log("TechStatCookie detected -> Popup hide " + now.toUTCString());
} else {
    document.getElementById("CookiePopup").style.display = "block";
    console.log("TechStatCookie not detected -> Popup show " + now.toUTCString());
}
}

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot one thing. var result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )TechStatCookie=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie); if (result) { techStatCookie = result[1]; } This is the code to get the <techStat> value of cookie

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
<anonymous> https://example.com/popup.js:5
```

For the above error, you need to add example.js script tag at the bottom of your HTML page

```
Uncaught TypeError: _yesCookie is not a function
onclick https://example.com/:1
example.com:1:1
```

To fixed the second error you need to remove try & catch block